# GCP instances not connecting via port on free tier

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, port

On Google Cloud Platform, I have set up two instances that need to connect via port 6333.

However, due to port blocking, I am unable to consistently sync the instances. I have searched for Linux commands to enable this and read up on firewall rules. However, I don’t have a solution to making the ports connect yet. Any advice on how to solve for this?

I’m trying to also diagnose if

this is this a firewall issue or
is there anyway to overcome the port blocking or
do i need to upgrade to free tier simply?
Tried contacting gcp support, been told that I need to pay for the support ($100/month). Hence trying out this forum for now.

Update based on comments:

- Google Cloud Service: Compute Engine (Machine Configuration: Series E2, Machine Type e2 medium (2 vCPU, 4 GB Memory)
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- Firewall Configuration: Allow HTTP and HTTPS Traffic
- Firewall rules: Allow port access for port 6333 [See Attached Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eu8MW.jpg)
- Any software listening on port 6333: Another GCP instance with a similar setup

Comment: Which Google Cloud service? Which OS? Which firewall? What firewall rules did you create? 
Do you have software listening on port 6333 and what is the software? Edit your question and provide details on what you set up and what you configured.

Comment: free tiers isn't the problem here. can you provide more details?

Comment: Thank you for your guidance, I have updated the post with details as requested. Please let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: What software is listening on port 6333? Firewalls allow traffic, you need something that opens the port and listens for connections.

Comment: The software listening on port 6333 is a crypto node instance, that I am using for an online course to build a cryptocurrency.